# Node.js MSSQL tedius ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql, tedious

I am trying to connect to MSSQL 2012 using NodeJS with the [mssql](https://patriksimek.github.io/node-mssql/) connection interface.

When attempting to connect I get the following error:

```
{ [ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED]
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to conncet to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `localhost` also does not work for me, however using the actual ip address of the machine does.

Comment: @amin.avan well it would depend on if you are running the database locally or not. If you are running the db locally localhost should work. If not then I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: @MattCarrier  I am getting a similar error when I try to connect to Azure SQL from my node js application. But there is no option of enabling or disabling TCP IP in there. Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The solution is to enable TCP connections which are disabled by default.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the screenshot. I thought I had it enabled because I saw remote connections were enabled in SSMS, but this was not.

Comment: How do you do this in Docker?

Comment: On windows 10 you can quickly access the configuration window by pressing  "window button + R" then type: "SQLServerManager13.msc"

Comment: I had to restart the SQL Server service after updating this, and it worked!

Answer (score 32):

My case wasn't exactly the same as Matt's, but his screenshot was enough to remember me what was missing.

[image]

As it is said [here](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html), when you are using the SQL Server Instance Name to connect to it, you must have SQL Server Browser running.

> options.instanceName
>
> The instance name to connect to. The SQL Server
> Browser service must be running on the database server, and UDP port
> 1434 on the database server must be reachable.
>
> (no default)
>
> Mutually exclusive with options.port.

Answer (score 24):

If somebody still struggles to connect despite doing all that was proposed.
In my case I had to manually set TCP Port property to 1433 in SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for ... -> TCP/IP -> IP Addresses -> IPAll.

[[image: 1]]

Comment: For anyone who got here - my issue was that TCP/IP wasn't enabled, even though SSMS could connect!  Enabling it in the configuration manager at the above location got it working for me.

Comment: This really did help!

Answer (score 22):

If after enabling the TCP connection and your configuration is still not working. Here's my own-configuration.

```
var config = {
    "user": 'admin',
    "password": 'password',
    "server": 'WINDOWS-PC',
    "database": 'database_name',
    "port": 61427, // make sure to change port
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "dialectOptions": {
        "instanceName": "SQLEXPRESS"
    }
};
```

Comment: This really did help!

Answer (score 6):

Best practice is to first verify the connection to the SQL server using a query analyzer (SQL Management Studio (Windows) or SQLPro for MSSQL (Mac)) using the same protocol, port and credentials as you wish to use via your application.

In Management Studio, the format is Server,Port (e.g. 192.168.1.10,1433); and you'll probably be using SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication.

---

Steps to configure the SQL Server:

Install with Mixed Authentication, if you intend to use SQL Server Authentication.

Setup SQL Server to listen on TCP on a fixed port number:

- SQL Configuration Manager SQL Server Network Configuration

  - Protocols for {Instance}

    - TCP/IP - Enabled
      (double-click)
    - IP Address (on all desired interfaces)

      - TCP Dynamic Ports = BLANK!  (not zero)
      - TCP Port  - 1433  (or desired port)

Comment: It worked for me but only when I set `1433` to `TCP Port` of `IPAll` section. Setting the `TCP Dynamic port` to `BLANK` and `TCP Port` to `1433` for Ioopback address i.e 127.0.0.1 alone did not work. I am using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Thank you, this answer is what helped me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was a configuration issue.This was the wrong configuration

```
let config = {
server: 'localhost',
authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
        userName: 'sa', // update me
        password: 'xxxxx' // update me
    }
},
options: {
    database: 'SampleDB',
    validateBulkLoadParameters:false,
}}
```

Then I have added encrypt variable to the options.It solved my issue.Corrected configuration

```
let config = {
server: 'localhost',
authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
        userName: 'sa', // update me
        password: 'xxxxxx' // update me
    }
},
options: {
    database: 'SampleDB',
    validateBulkLoadParameters:false,
    encrypt: false,
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

```
**Please follow the connection configuration and little test:**

//Declare global variable
var http = require('http');
var events = require('events');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sql = require('mssql');<br/>
var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; 
//Create an http server
http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 var Connection = require('tedious').Connection; 
//Configure the connection 
    var config = {  
        userName: '<user id>',  
        password: '<password>',  
        server: '<system ip>',  
        options: {database: '<database name>'}  
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        console.log("Connected"); 
        executeStatement();     
    }); 

function executeStatement() {  
        request = new Request("select getdate();", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });
     var result = "";  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                result+= column.value + " ";  
              }  
            });  
            console.log(result);  
            result ="";  
        });  

        connection.execSql(request);  
};
  return res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

//Post configuration test on browser:
http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 2):

Apart from setting TCP port no to 1433.
If you are getting "Connection lost - Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed" error

This error will also come if you use options.encrypt: true on Node v12+ with old SQL Server versions.

This is caused by Node v12 requiring TLS 1.2.

- install the TLS 1.2 security patch for your SQL Server
- run node with backwards compatibility flag:

  `node --tls-min-v1.0`

  eg:  `node --tls-min-v1.0 app.js`
- disable encrypted communication by setting

  `options.encrypt: false` (optional)

Config Object:

```
const config = {
      user: '...',
      password: '...',
      server: 'localhost', 
      database: '...',
      'options.encrypt': false   
   }
```

**Ref:** https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/903#issuecomment-614597523

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't connect with 'localhost' although I use 'localhost' in SQL Management Studio and other applications.
When I used Computer Name (network address), it worked!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I needed to start sqlserver using docker first on my mac using this command

`sudo docker start sqlserver`

Answer (score 0):

For me changing this condition from 'No' to 'Yes' worked:

```
    switch (key) {
      case 'instance':
        return this.config.options.instanceName
      case 'trusted':
        return this.config.options.trustedConnection ? 'Yes' : 'Yes'
```

It just doesn't load the value from the options object even if I provide it.

I hardcoded this change in file **\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error
**ConnectionError: Failed to connect to : - D42A0000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol**

```
dbConfig1 = {
    user: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    server: 'XXXX',
    port: XXXX,
    database: 'XXXX'
}
```

Solution:
I added "encrypt": false.

```
dbConfig1 = {
    user: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    server: 'XXXX',
    port: XXXX,
    database: 'XXXX',
    options: {
        "encrypt": false
    }
}
```