# Trouble making nodejs mysql connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to make a simple connection between my nodejs server and my mysql db (using Microsoft SQL server manager studio v14), below is my code and the error message appearing in my console window.

here is my code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'superadmin',
        password: '***',
        server: 'localhost', 
        database: 'XXX' 
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from Schools', function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

The error I am getting looks like this:

```js
Server is running..
tedious deprecated The default value for `options.encrypt` will change from `false` to `true`. Please pass `false` explicitly if you want to retain current behaviour. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:212:23
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:275:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1004:14)
    at C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:869:25
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:154:9)
    at Socket.onError (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:170:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError:
   { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at ConnectionError (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1004:30)
    at C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:869:25
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:154:9)
    at Socket.onError (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:170:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
     message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)',
     code: 'ESOCKET' },
  name: 'ConnectionError' }
{ ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at Request._query (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1299:37)
    at Request._query (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:497:11)
    at Request.query (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1242:12)
    at C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\test.js:24:17
    at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (C:\Users\smr09\Desktop\Code\ou\db_test\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:269:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }
```

I am rather new at this particularly with dealing with databases. Can someone explain what the error means?

Comment: Googling the error looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577248/node-js-mssql-tedius-connectionerror-failed-to-connect-to-localhost1433-conn

Comment: Is your db running @ localhost:1433?

Also verify your credentials. Try logging in with the same credentials using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: did you try putting `encrypt: false` in your `config = {}` object to see if that made any difference?

Comment: Did you get its answer?

Comment: no, I reinstalled and it worked, not sure what the issue was.

Comment: You must use:
mysql = require('mysql');

sqlserver = require("mssql");

Answer (score 5):

Add this line to the config:

```
options: {
    encrypt: false
}
```

It will finally look like:

```
var config = {
    user: 'superadmin',
    password: '***',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'XXX' ,
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put encrypt: false in your config{}, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

your error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not
>   connect (sequence)

My problem was resolved by adding port

```
var config = {
            user: 'superadmin',
            password: '***',
            server: 'localhost', 
            database: 'XXX',
            port: '',
        };
```